# Apple Instruments slows down app when analyzing memory allocations

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, instruments

When running my app in the simulator and analyzing its memory allocations using Instruments, the App runs very slow, it runs at less than 1/30 of its normal speed.

The app uses about 50 MB RAM and has approximately 900,000 life objects (according to Instruments).

Could this be the reason for the slow performance?

When running in the app on the device or in the simulator without using Instruments, it performs well (except the memory issue I am trying to debug).

- Do you have any idea on how to solve this issue?
- Did you encounter slow performance using the Memory Allocation
  instruments?
- Would you consider having more than 900,000 life
  objects "concerning"?

[image]

Comment: I encounter performance issues using the simulator. I only instrument on simulator when performance is not in play for what i am trying to measure/observe. Otherwise, instruments also slows down processes in devices, but to a much lesser extent. Leaks instruments will however have a significant performance hit every 10 seconds.

Comment: Expect overhead added when instruments runs. If your app allocates tons of objects, expect tons of overhead.

Comment: Slightly off-topic, but bear in mind that the simulator is near useless for assessing actual memory usage. Remember it's an API simulator, not a hardware emulator. You *must* profile on a real device if you're chasing memory issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Considering your Analyzer performance issue

In your specific case monitoring the app over a long period of time will not be necessary, as you reach the state of high memory consumption very soon. You could simply stop recording at this point. Then you won't have problems navigating through the different views and statistics to find the cause of the memory issue.

### Analyzing the memory issue

Slowing down is normal. **1/30 sounds quite alarming**.

You probably should track how the amount of life objects and the memory usage change while you use the app.

It is difficult to decide if a certain amount of life objects at a specific point in time is critical (though 900,000 seems very high).

In general: if life objects and memory usage grow continuously and don't shrink, that is a bad sign.

If you take a look `Statistics -> Object Summary` (Screenshot), `Live Bytes` should be a lot smaller than `Overall Bytes` and the amount of `#Living` objects should be a lot smaller than the amount of `#Transitory` objects.

[image]

The second thing you can look at, is the `Call Tree` view.
It gives you a nice overview of which parts of the application are responsible for reserving large amount of memory:

[image]

### Possible solutions

Once you detect the parts of your code that are responsible for reserving the large memory amount you can look for retain-cycles or you could try to use more autorelease pools in that spot.

Comment: I have added a screenshot of Instruments to my question. The relations between life objects and transient objects, etc. seem to be ok. But the absolute numbers look worrisome to me. Do you have any tip on how to tackle this issue (considering the slow performance of Instruments)? I am parsing very complex XML documents with deep hierarchies into Core Data. I try to keep the memory footprint as low as possible (by using autoreleasepools, ARC, etc) as documented by Apple, but have no clue on how to find the memory issue when Instruments is sluggish and stops working after a couple of minutes.

Comment: I currently don't have any idea how you could improve the performance of instruments. One alternative would be to stop the recording after a minute or two and analyze the memory consumption afterwards, for example by looking at the 'CallTree'. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have enough available disk space. I had 8gb left and it seems like that was too little. Instruments was extreeemely slow. Used a minute just to start and didn't quite get around at all.

I cleared out more disk space and then it suddenly went back to being fast as before.